# How do I totally get rid of Norton Utilities

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, norton-antivirus

Alright, so I treated myself to a new computer for Christmas. Windows7 64-bit, yada yada yada. Uninstalled Norton Security using Windows7 uninstall program, installed Microsoft Security Essentials in it's place. From a cold boot, I still get the screen from Norton asking me if I wanna sign up for the free six months, which I don't. Guess Windows7 uninstall left behind some pieces. Anyone know how I can get rid of this Norton screen?

EDIT: @ Revolter: Great. Used Norton Removal Tool Successfully. Now I get a different pop-up window ALWAYS reminding me if I want to activate Norton Online Backup. What does one have to do to FINALLY get rid of these people?

Comment: Just to clarify as a side note, Windows Add/Remove panel (XP, Vista, 7) do nothing but run the uninstaller provided by the software, which is set in the registry. This is Norton purposely leaving behind components, not Windows 7 failing to remove everything.

Comment: My apologies to Microsoft. I notmally never use their uninstall program. I've been using Revo Uninstaller for quite some time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is [Revo uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/)

> Revo uninstaller helps you to
>   uninstall software and remove unwanted
>   programs installed on your computer
>   even if you have problems uninstalling
>   and cannot uninstall them from
>   "Windows Add or Remove Programs"
>   control panel applet ...

Or

[Norton removal tool](http://service1.symantec.com/Support/tsgeninfo.nsf/docid/2005033108162039)

> The Norton Removal Tool uninstalls all
>   Norton
>   2009/2008/2007/2006/2005/2004/2003
>   products, Norton 360 and Norton
>   SystemWorks 12.0 from your computer.

---

Or

use **MSCONFIG** tool to check for any startup process AND services related to Symatec and disable them, and take a look to **Sheduled Tasks** entries for any planned tasks.

Comment: I'll try Norton removal too, since I understand Revo Uninstaller does not yet have a version for 64-bit systems.

Comment: @Patriot: I'm using Revo on a 64-bit Windows and it's working fine...

Comment: Norton Removal Tool worked fine. Then I was able to get rid of all the leftover files & folders without a hitch. Left the registry alone since I've not had good experiences tinkering there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Msconfig/Startup/Uncheck 'Norton Online Backup'. Fixed. Sorta. Good enough, anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [AppRemover](http://www.appremover.com):

> AppRemover™ is a free utility developed by OPSWAT that enables
>   thorough, easy uninstallation of security applications from your
>   computer.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered

- wiping the partition/disk
- reinstalling Windows 7 fresh, without all the pre-installed apps?

That will 100% ensure you do not have any remnants from Symantec and the Norton product.

It <strike>may</strike> will have the side-benefit of ridding the machine of any other crapware that came preinstalled.

Comment: +1 way to go, not only will this take care of Norton but also any other nonsensical bloat OEM's have the courtesy to install on new systems :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do any or all of the following to get rid of Norton:

1) Reformat your hard drive and re-install Windows7 like some others suggested ... absolutely will work
2) Search for all registry keys that have Norton anywhere within the keys or values, then delete them
3) Search for all files on your computer that are associated with Norton, then delete them
4) Look in your Scheduled Tasks associated with Norton and remove them
5) Look in the services running on your computer associated with Norton, disable them or delete them or have them setup to be started manually

*I would be cautious as to download and use any freeware applications that claim to remove applications for you ... they usually contain all sorts of adware, spyware and malware that you don't even notice. You also probably agree to let them do whatever they want because it's in the End User License Agreement that you agree to when you install the program ... no one ever reads those things.

You best bet would be to reformat and re-install Windows7 ... this sucks though if you already have Office and other large applications on the machine because they take a long time to install or you may not have the disks for those.

Comment: Norton is created by Symantec so you might also want to search for that along with Norton.

Answer (score 0):

I got rid of the same persistent popup reminder inviting me to sign up for Norton Online Backup by going to the Control Panel and using the "Programs and Features" function to uninstall the "Activate Norton Online Backup" program. Gone!